# Getting double quotes in Json response

Tags: json, arraylist, webservice-client

[{"State":"serverX","freq":{"selenium_users":4786,"eclipse_users":1319,}}]

I am genrating a Json response from a service fetching data from data base but i am getting double quotes in response.
Can anybody tell how to avoid these double quotes in response.

Comment: this seems like a valid json string that you can get from any service returning json, use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate json...if is without double codes, it will most likely be the json object, and to get that you will need to convert the json string you got from the server on the client side

Comment: thanks for the help.
I got your point and yes this is right.